# Algorithm for Log2 of integers in binary representation

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

Let $x = \sum_{i=0}^N a_i 2^i$ where $a_i$ takes the values of either $0$ or $1$. It is easy to find lower and upper bounds to the value of $\log_2(x)$ simply by finding the most significant bit. How can I find the exact value of $\log_2(x)$ using the values $a_i$?

I would like to have some closed form, possibly using summation. I am not interested in efficient calculation on hardware or mere approximations.

Comment: At MSE you are expected to show what you have tried to solve the problem, and say where you are stuck. Asking/telling people to do what you want isn't going to get you many answers (or friends).

Comment: No that is not the answer that is the question. You merely substituted the x in my question

Comment: In the OP I showed that I understand how to give upper and lower bounds to the solution. I want to know the exact solution, thats where I am stuck.